# If I colour $n$ vertices independently, randomly with $n^{(1-x)}$ colours, why is the size of the colour classes $(1+o(1))n^x$?

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, coloring, random-graphs

By $o(1)$, I mean 'little-o' of $1$.

A paper I'm reading uses this result, but I can't see where it comes from.

Thanks.